# Kubernetes Helm chart requirements.yaml file dependencies false condition

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am using the Kubernetes Helm requirements.yaml file for dependencies addition. Based on the values.yaml condition, it will create the dependencies pods.

Here I want to execute required dependencies when apache.enabled == false

```
values.yaml

external_apache:
  enabled: false
```

#### File requirements.yaml

```
dependencies:
- name:
  version:
  repository:
  condition: external_apache.enabled
```

How do I add a false condition?

I have tried the below condition, but it's not working:

```
condition: external_apache.enabled == false
```

Comment: The correct syntax is `condition: external_apache.enabled` but are you sure the file is getting values from values.yaml?

Comment: yes. Getting values from values.yaml file.
Here am trying to read **enabled: false** condition
if  **enabled: true**  then we can use use  **condition: external_apache.enabled**

Comment: Here I am validating  two conditions.

1. if  **enabled: false**  --- adding some dependencies
2. if  **enabled: true**   ---  adding some other sependencies

But am not getting correct syntax when **enabled: false**

Comment: I also hit the exactly same issue with error issue when trying to install the chart. `Error: found in requirements.yaml, but missing in charts/ directory: subchart1` The version of helm is `v2.11.0`.

Answer (score 5):

What version of Helm are you using?

There was a similar issue in the Kubernetes repository on GitHub:

[Unable to use condition in 'requirements.yaml' #2111](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/issues/2111)

The solution was to upgrade Helm to v2.2.0+. In that version, condition support was added.

[**Helm 2 to Helm 3 upgrade note:**](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/v2_v3_migration/)

> Chart apiVersion bumped to "v2" for following specification changes:
>
> - **Dynamically linked chart dependencies moved to [Chart.yaml](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#the-chartyaml-file) (requirements.yaml removed and requirements --> dependencies)**
> - Library charts (helper/common charts) can now be added as dynamically linked chart dependencies
> - Charts have a type metadata field to define the chart to be of an application or library chart. It is application by default which means it is renderable and installable
> - Helm 2 charts (apiVersion=v1) are still installable

In the [Helm documentation](https://docs.helm.sh/developing_charts/#tags-and-condition-fields-in-requirements-yaml) or [repository](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/blob/master/docs/charts.md#tags-and-condition-fields-in-requirementsyaml), there is an explanation of how the condition works:
(I've added some comments to make reading easier)

**Condition** - The condition field holds one or more YAML paths (delimited by commas). 
**Tags** - The tags field is a YAML list of labels to associate with this chart.

```
# parentchart/requirements.yaml
dependencies:
      - name: subchart1
        repository: http://localhost:10191
        version: 0.1.0
        condition: subchart1.enabled, global.subchart1.enabled
        tags:
          - front-end        #(chart should be disabled because the tags.front-end is “false” in values.yaml file , but ...)
          - subchart1        #(subchart1.enabled condition path is present in values.yaml file and it has "true" value...)
                             #(this condition, so it overrides tag front-end and this chart will be enabled)

      - name: subchart2
        repository: http://localhost:10191
        version: 0.1.0
        condition: subchart2.enabled,global.subchart2.enabled
                  #(as soon as no one from these paths is exists in values.yaml this condition has ho effect)

        tags:
          - back-end        #(chart should be enabled because the tags.back-end is “true” in values.yaml file)
          - subchart2       #(and there is no condition path found in values.yaml to override it)
```

If this **condition path** exists in the top parent’s `values` and resolves to a boolean value, the chart will be enabled or disabled based on that boolean value.
Only the first valid path found in the list is evaluated and **if no paths exist then the condition has no effect**.

In the top parent’s values, all charts with **tags** can be enabled or disabled by specifying the tag and a boolean value.

```
# parentchart/values.yaml

subchart1:
  enabled: true          #(this could be found from requirements as subchart1.enabled and override tags in this case)
tags:
  front-end: false      #(this disables charts with tag front-end)
  back-end: true        #(this enables charts with tag back-end)
```

The logic and sequence of conditions and tags are described in [Tags and Condition Resolution](https://docs.helm.sh/developing_charts/#tags-and-condition-resolution):

- **Conditions (when set in values) always override tags**. The first condition path that exists wins and subsequent ones for that chart are ignored.
- Tags are evaluated as ‘if any of the chart’s tags are true then enable the chart’.
- Tags and conditions values must be set in the top parent’s values.
- The tags: key in values must be a top level key. **Globals and nested tags: tables are not currently supported.**

You can also set tags and conditions in the command line:

```
helm install --set tags.front-end=true --set subchart2.enabled=false
```

Answer (score 2):

Helm version `v2.2.2` worked, while `v2.10.0` didn't.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [documentation](https://docs.helm.sh/developing_charts/#tags-and-condition-fields-in-requirements-yaml) and the answer from @VAS, the answer to your question is **it's not possible to use a negation of a condition in requirements.yaml**.

Answer (score 0):

Though its a bit late, but users may find it helpful. I am not running helm install for the parent chart from command line, but, I have a shell script for running it and another shell script for environment properties.

I have set the conditional boolean values to true or false in environment script and using the values in other script which runs helm for parent helm chart, I have set individual child chart **enabled** property in parent's values.yaml.

> Also, in version 3.0.0+, the configuration done earlier in
> requirements.yaml  are now done in parent's chart.yaml itself.