# Negate a boolean value in helm yaml file

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have 3 helm charts. I would like to deploy either two or one based on a condition. global.useFirstChart is a boolean variable.

```
- name: first-chart
  version: 0.1.0
  condition: charts.useFirstChart
- name: second-chart
  version: 0.1.0
  condition: not charts.useFirstChart
- name: third-chart
  version: 0.1.0
  condition: not global.useFirstChart
```

However when we tried using this chart, if useFirstChart equals true it deploys all three, if it equals false, it deploys second-chart and third-chart (like expected).
I used '**not**' to negate the boolean value, but it doesn't work.

Also we're suspecting the value is string not bool because we set it from Terraform.
is there a way to negate the bool value in helm ?

is there a workaround to deploy specific charts and not others ?

Comment: I'm not an expert but I bet the value is a string too. Did you try something like: `if eq charts.useFirstChart "true"` just to make sure it's the case? I know there is a better way to do that.

Comment: or you can do `if charts.deploy` and pass some string via terraform to the service that you want to deploy, and leave it blank for the other services.

Comment: @JuanFontes condition expects a boolean value, I thought "if eq charts.useFirstChart "true" " doesn't return a bool.


I'm working on putting a condition in Chart.yaml. please specify in which file I would put an if statement because in Chart.yaml, editor shows error when I do that.

Comment: If you're launching this from Terraform, can you use multiple `helm_release` resources and set the condition there?  I've run into several operational problems with Helm "umbrella charts" that install multiple applications together and generally found it easier to manage multiple chart installations separately.

Comment: But I think [Kubernetes Helm chart requirements.yaml file dependencies false condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50753548/kubernetes-helm-chart-requirements-yaml-file-dependencies-false-condition) is the same question, and in a Helm `requirements.yaml`/`Chart.yaml` file there's no way to specify that a subchart should be installed if a value is false.